# Python: why can't descriptors be instance variables?

Tags: python, scope, descriptor

Say I define this descriptor:

```
class MyDescriptor(object):

   def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._value = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del(self._value)
```

And I use it in this:

```
class MyClass1(object):
    value = MyDescriptor()


>>> m1 = MyClass1()
>>> m1.value = 1
>>> m2 = MyClass1()
>>> m2.value = 2
>>> m1.value
2
```

So `value` is a class attribute and is shared by all instances.

Now if I define this:

```
class MyClass2(object)
    value = 1

>>> y1 = MyClass2()
>>> y1.value=1
>>> y2 = MyClass2()
>>> y2.value=2
>>> y1.value
1
```

In this case `value` is an instance attribute and is not shared by the instances.

Why is it that when `value` is a descriptor it can only be a class attribute, but when `value` is a simple integer it becomes an instance attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're ignoring the `instance` parameter in your implementation of `MyDescriptor`. That is why it *appears* to be a class attribute. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
class MyDescriptor(object):

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance._value = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del(instance._value)
```

Comment: How would you implement MyDescriptor() to make it behave like an instance variable?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: It worked. Thanks! My previous comment was made before I saw the updates you made to your answer.

Comment: Great! I usually try to get the answer up before going off to test sample code. :)

Comment: Continuation: Simple, just operate on the instance :)

Answer (score 0):

Will not work if you try the code below:

```
class MyClass1(object):
    value = MyDescriptor()
    value2 = MyDescriptor()

c = MyClass1()
c.value = 'hello'
c.value2 = 'world'

# where c.value also equals to "world"
```